# Find an equation of the tangent plane to the given surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Question: Find the equation of the tangent plane to the surface with equation $z = 3y^2-2x^2+x$ at the point $(2,-1,-3)$.

My attempts:

$\nabla f_x$ $= -4x+1$

$\nabla f_y$ $= 6y$

Setting up the equation I get:

$z+3 =$ $-4(x+1-2) + 6(y+1)$

combining and then condensing gives me:

$z = (-4x+4) + (6y+6) -3$

$z = -4x + 6y +(10-3)$

$z = -4x+6y+7$

I must be missing some fundamental property or idea here in my calculation as the answer in the book is:
$z = -7x-6y+5$

I apologize for the remedial question, I know this site should be used for questions above this, but this site is my only way to get help while studying ahead in lieu of a professor. I thank you for your patience.

Comment: Your error appears to be in setting up the equation of the plane. It should be $\nabla f\cdot(\mathbf r-\mathbf r_0)=0$, i.e., $f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)=z-z_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the partial derivatives to find a normal vector to the surface. At the point $(2,-1,-3)$ you have $f_x(2,-1) = -7$ and $f_y(2,-1) = -6$ so that one normal vector is $\langle -7,-6,-1\rangle$.  The equation of the tangent plane is given by $$-7(x-2) - 6(y+1) - (z+3) = 0$$ which simplifies to $z = -7x - 6y + 5$.

Comment: Thank you for your help and clarification